# Web Implementation for Java interactive game

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am working on a project Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe. I have made Java code which is taking input from console and giving output to the console. I want to implement the same on Web. Sample code snippet in Java looks like:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int tour = 1;
     Game g = new Game();
     while (g.isEndOfGame() == 0) {
        if (tour % 2 == 0) {
            g.play(run());
            System.out.println(g.changeToString());
        } else {
            int move;
             do{
                int bigSquare = scan.nextInt() - 1;
                int smallSquare = scan.nextInt() - 1;
                move = bigSquare * 9 + smallSquare;
            } while (!g.contains(move));
            g.play(move);
            System.out.println(g.changeToString());
        }
        tour++;
    }
}
```

In web,
I have made 81 small blocks through HTML. How to take input on mouse click and pass to the Main class to variables bigSquare and smallSquare and similarly how to display that index in JSP?

Comment: You haven't posted what you've tried so far. Can you post your HTML/JSP code here so that others can evaluate the code to offer solutions on it?

Comment: Since code is too big, you can view here http://pastebin.com/CpRiWg8i

Comment: Nope. Not going there. You need to post the relevant part that is failing as part of your question. See here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Comment: I have made 81 grids. Now when I click on some particular grid I should know the index number and pass to my Java class. I don't know how to get that value and pass to java function

Comment: Give each grid element a unique id e.g. `id="8_1"`, then simply handle the click event: `onclick="doSomething(this);"`. And in the `doSomething()` function (or whatever you wish to call it), simply interrogate the id of the HTMLElement that is sent to the function to know the grid location. Or submit it back to your server, if you're going to do the logic server side rather than in the client via JavaScript.

Comment: I have 3 Java classes. And one main class contains play function. Now how to call that play function.

Comment: Your Java classes are server side. If you're going to do it like that, then you're going to have consider the differences between how your web UI interacts with your API as opposed to your shell based app. Abstract what you require into a core game JAR and call it from both console and web. Personally, I would just do this in client side JavaScript. It's such a simple game. You don't really need to be doing this server side. Up to yourself though :)

Comment: No, Its not that simple game. I have used Minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning. This is part of Aritificial Intelligence. You can assume my code has three classes and many functions. One main function interact with all other functions. It takes input parameter from console and print the output. Now I need to take input from mouse click instead from console. I hope that I am clear to you.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Simply do what I suggested above. Create your grid, give each element a unique id, based on its grid location, capture the onclick event and then submit the value back to your server side code via AJAX, or a REST API, or whatever method you're using to go between client and server.